# Warning:com.bugsense.trace.BugSense

Tags: java, android

Warning:com.bugsense.trace.BugSense: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':sdk:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> Job failed, see logs for details

Comment: Note: Just to give a background as to where this error arises: warning shown when running on device or emulator, it grade syncs without an issue.